# If $A=B+C$, $A,B,C$ are semipositive definite matrices, prove that $\text{im}A=\text{im}B+\text{im}C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If $A=B+C$, here $A,B,C$ are **semi**-positive definite matrices, prove that $\text{im}A=\text{im}B+\text{im}C$.

It is trivial to prove $\text{im}A\subset\text{im}B+\text{im}C$. For the other side, a vector in $\text{im}B+\text{im}C$ can be written as $Bx+Cy$. And we derive the following:
\begin{align}
\\xAx=xBx+xCx
\\yAy=yBy+yCy
\end{align}

Our goal is to find $z$ such that $Az=Bx+Cy$, but I have no ideas how to use the positive condition.

Comment: What is meant by ${\rm Im} B + {\rm Im} C$?

Comment: @K.Jiang It's the sum of two vector (sub)spaces, $E + F := \{u + v \mid u \in E, v \in F\}$.

Comment: Just use the fact that $A$ is invertible to find such vector $z$.

Comment: @Jkbb $A$ is positive semidefinite. I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use the property that if $T\ge 0$ then
$$\|Tx\|\le \|T\|\langle Tx,x\rangle \quad (*)$$
Since $A$ is semi-positive definite then $Ax=0$ implies $Bx=Cx=0.$ Indeed if $A=0$ then $$0=\langle Ax,x\rangle = \langle Bx,x\rangle + 
\langle Cx,x\rangle $$  Hence $$\langle Bx,x\rangle= \langle Cx,x\rangle=0$$ By $(*)$ we get $Bx=Cx=0.$ The implication $$Bx=Cx=0\implies Ax=0$$ is obvious. Therefore $$\ker A=\ker B\cap \ker C$$ Taking the orthogonal complement gives $${\rm Im}\, A={\rm Im}\, B+{\rm Im} \,C$$